# Can you disable automatic horizontal scrolling in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, editor, settings, eclipse-cdt, horizontal-scrolling

Sometimes when I jump into source code, e.g. from search or when looking up the declaration of something, the Eclipse text editor tries to display nearby long lines by horizontal scrolling. This happens even if the item I jumped to is well within the display without scrolling. I find this rather annoying, so:

Is there a way to disable this? I have searched in vain through all the editor settings.

Specifically, this is about Eclipse CDT, but I suppose the behaviour is the same in JDT.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to happen in other eclipse editors too (like [PDT for PHP](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools.pdt/msg00777.html))

It could have been related with the [`ScrolledFormText`](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform.swt/msg41228.html), but the [Plugin Spy](http://www.eclipse.org/pde/incubator/spy/) tells us a `WorkbenchWindow` class is concerned, as well as an [`AbstractDecoratedTextEditor`](http://help.eclipse.org/ganymede/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/texteditor/AbstractDecoratedTextEditor.html), that is in essence an [`org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor`](http://help.eclipse.org/ganymede/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/texteditor/AbstractTextEditor.html).

The [source of that `AbstractTextEditor`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/ui/texteditor/AbstractTextEditor.java.htm) indicates having:

- a **ScrollLinesAction** for vertical scrolling
- a **TextNavigationAction** for settings the cursor and potentially triggering horizontal scrolling

I am not sure how to change that behavior, except by contributing somehow to the active editor identifier (for instance, for java, "`org.eclipse.jdt.ui.ClassFileEditor`"), and modifying that `Action`.

Comment: For the time being I tracked it back to ITextViewer.revealRange().

Comment: @starblue: Interesting. Did you manage to override its behavior ?

Comment: Upvote for the Plugin Spy but where can I get it? ALT + SHIFT + F1 does not bring it up for me here on a Windows 8 machine. Could you look in you installed software and tell me the feature group for it?

Comment: @DanielSokolowski are you with Eclipse 4.x? Because I don't think you have a plugin spy there. As described in http://tomsondev.bestsolution.at/2011/07/01/eclipse-4-1-run-your-3-x-rcp-in-4-1/, the "live model tooling" (e4 core Tools) replaces it (http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipsePlatformDevelopment/article.html#eclipse4_e4tools). They have recently moved over to http://blog.vogella.com/2014/01/21/eclipse-e4-tools-update-site-for-kepler-and-luna/

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and found these open bugs for it on the Eclipse Bugs:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=314208

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=321189

You can prevent it from happening when you switch the Code Folding off and reload the file.

grtz,

T

Comment: This is a different issue where it doesn't scroll horizontally when it should. I don't have this problem, because I have folding disabled.

Answer (score 0):

right click on your eclipse shortcut and choose properties. in compatibility tab choose "windows xp(servicepack 3). http://www.vistax64.com/vista-general/133849-disable-dynamic-horizontal-scrolling-vista.html