# Eclipse: After Editing Long Lines Editor Window Automatically Scrolls to Beginning of Line

Tags: eclipse, editor, line, long-integer, autoscroll

Some of my Javascript lines of code are longer than the editor window view.  I have recently upgraded to the Helios version of Eclipse and noticed that after editing one of these long lines (I am scrolled to the right), after a few seconds the editor window will automatically scroll back to the left to the beginning of the line.  It breaks my concentration and it's so annoying!

Does anyone know how to stop this behavior?  I've searched around and haven't been able to find anything other than others being annoyed by this same issue!

I am not willing to turn on word wrap and wrap my lines :).

Comment: It seems like there isn't any way for the user to turn this off - the editor developer must do it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/594129/disable-automatic-horizontal-scrolling-in-eclipse

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I was having the same issue and found [these](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=314208) [open bugs](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=321189) for it on the Eclipse Bugs.

No sign there of having a fix for it, but you can prevent it from happening when you switch the Code Folding off and reload the file.

Comment: Thanks!  Additionally, you can prevent it from happening if you hit the 'Toggle Mark Occurrences' button in the toolbar (or Alt+Shift+O) so marking occurrences is OFF.  (just found this one :))

Comment: Ah!  Never mind my above comment.  It seems that it still does it.

Comment: Confirming this solution works (and that the bug is super annoying).

Comment: FYI, to navigate to switch off Code Folding: `Window > Preferences > PHP > Editor > Code Folding`

Comment: I had this issue only with Eclipse Indigo an JavaScript, same sollution as @achasinh said but going to JavaScript instead of PHP, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For java in eclipse :

Windows -> Preferences -> Java ->Editors ->Folding -> Enable Folding (uncheck)

For HTML, JSP, XML etc in eclispe :
Windows -> Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Structured Text Editors -> Enable Folding (uncheck)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Mac OSX, press OPTION + COMMAND + O to turn off "Toggle Mark Occurrences" - it looks like a highlighter in the toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

I turned off Toggle Breadcrumb, and it fixed my problem.